# Couldn't find "Hello.so"

Tags: java, android, c++, java-native-interface

I need to integrate C++ code with Java code using JNI. I do have the `NativeCallHandler.java` which declares the interface i need to call. I also got the `Android.mk`, and `LOCAL_MODULE` is set to `Hello`.

But I got error saying that it couldn't find 'Hello.so'. I don't know what I did is not correct.

Could somebody help me out? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your lib will be named **libHello.so**

Answer (score 0):

set "LD_LIBRARY_PATH" before run program,

`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/so`

> follow my [java-native-interface-jni-tutorial](https://github.com/ckelsel/java-native-interface-jni-tutorial.git) if necessary

NOTE:HelloWorld.java, HelloWorld.h, HelloWord.c,libHelloWorld.so are in same directory

1. javac HelloWorld.java -> HelloWorld.class
2. javah -jni HelloWord  -> HelloWorld.h
3. implement HelloWord.c
4. gcc  -fpic -shared HelloWorld.c -o libHelloWorld.so
5. export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=`pwd`
6. java HelloWorld